# ASP.NET API Controller method custom route - Include current URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, sitecore, custom-component, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to create a custom route for an API Controller, that has the following structure:

```
/{currentUrl}/{methodName}
```

`currentUrl` does not come as a parameter.

Example:

```
/tool/compute/download
```

where "download" is the name of the method, and "/tool/compute/" is the current page we are on.

Just to mention, I am using Sitecore.

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some samples, what you are actually targeting for?

Comment: I just edited my post and provided an example

Comment: Does `tool` is your root directory name and `compute` is controller name?

Comment: No, it is the link to the actual page (using Sitecore). No controller name in the link. I forgot to mention that I am using Sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a method that takes the tool name as an agument, like this:

```
    [Route("tool/{toolName}/download")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string toolName)
    {
        var path = GetPathByToolName(toolName);
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The thing is that {currentUrl} it's generated through Sitecore. I need to take it as it is. Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't know sitecore and I don't know if they got a solution for that. If not I would try to extend the routing at runtime. http://www.strathweb.com/2014/07/building-strongly-typed-route-provider-asp-net-web-api/ explains how to extend and plug in your own custom logic into the attribute routing engine.